# php include file only if existing

Tags: php, caching, include, warnings

I'm testing some caching code in php:

```
   if (is_readable($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime
     < filemtime($cachefile))) 
  {
            include($cachefile);
   […]
```

**What it should do:** 
Run include only if $cachefile already exists. If not it's supposed to proceed without trying to include $cachefile.
**What it does:**
It tries to load $cachefile every time therefore creating a php warning when it does not exist.

I have no idea how to fix it since I tried just about everything that would normally prevent include from being excecuted. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: use `isset` function instead of is_readable

Comment: http://php.net/is_readable: *`is_readable` — Tells whether a file exists and is readable* - it sounds that you're doing some wrong elsewhere.

Comment: as hakre already wrote, there error must be anywhere else - did you check the line number of the error? is this realy the file and line where the failing include happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
if (isset($cachefile) && ((time() - $cachetime) < filemtime($cachefile))) 
{
    include($cachefile);
}
```

you can use `isset` or `file_exists` functions, here is documentations =>

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

**Note**: `Wrap time() - $cachetime` in () , also make sure `$cachefile`'s url is right

Answer (score 0):

if(file_exists('file.php'))
    include 'file.php';

Comment: `is_readable()` is fine. You're just suggesting a function that does less (but might equally work, however the chance is likely it produces the same effects).